# Codeigniter page loads on localhost but 404's on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

If I go to:

http://localhost/entry

I see my test page. If I go to:

http://examplesite.com/entry

I get a 404 page. And I don't mean the Codeigniter 404 page but the default apache one. The code bases are identical.

The homepage works fine but any inner pages 404. This is the contents of my root .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes access to the system folder by users. Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller, 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    # When your application folder isn't in the system folder. This snippet prevents user access to the application folder. Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file, such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the request to index.php.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Mod rewrite is enabled on the server verified with phpinfo(). Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you set base_url()? in `config.php`?

Comment: @Hekmat I did set it as `http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see Apache's `404` status page instead of CodeIgniter's `404`, mod_rewrite is not active.

[`phpinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) only tells you, if a module is loaded, not if it's configured properly. You can check reliably, if `mod_rewrite` is active, by adding garbage to your .htaccess inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>...</IfModule>`. When it is active, you will get a `500` server error.

To use [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in `.htaccess` files, [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) and [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) must be set for the appropriate directory, e.g.

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

or even

```
AllowOverride All # default if <= 2.3.8
Options All # this is the default
```

---

Unrelated, but [`%{REQUEST_URI}`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) starts with a slash, so the first two rules (with these `RewriteCond`s) will never match.

Comment: Hmm Mod rewrite is already on it seems. I ran this command on the server's terminal `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and it returned `Module rewrite already enabled`. Also previously when it wasn't enabled the homepage didn't work but after enabling it it works now just not the inner pages.

Comment: And what about `AllowOverride` and `Options`?

Comment: That was it, I had to set AllowOverride all in the httpd cofig file. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the site's base url is set to your local address, if you installed CI on your live site, then chances are your base url is set to that URL. Try verifying it in the config file.