# Laravel 5.4 - Routes not working

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I've setup a fresh ubuntu mini  installation and installed apache2 and PHP. (also tried it with latest stable ubuntu)
I've also installed some moduls, amongst others the moduls listed in the [laravel installation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4):

```
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension
```

I also installed:

**libapache2-mod-php**,**git** and **curl, php-curl**:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install php-curl
sudo apt-get install git
```

Now I copied a whole laravel project from my apache server from windows.
Then I executed

```
chmod 775 -R *
```

and

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *
```

However, the routes are not working.

e.g. http://192.168.2.100/selenium/public/start

Should show my start page, instead I get:

> Not Found: The requested URL /selenium/public/start was not found on this server.`

So I researched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16899065/4684797) on stackoverflow.

From the answer:

> ```
> Try to navigate to your expected route prepend it with /index.php/, in
> your case: http://localhost/laravel/index.php/users. 
> If it works (no 404) then you problem is with the Rewrite Module configuration of
> Apache HTTP, you should follow the next steps.
> ```

---

So I tried to call my page like suggested:

```
http://192.168.2.100/selenium/public/index.php/start
```

That worked. So there is a problem with the Rewrite Module Configuration.

He/She suggested to add `RewriteBase /directory/` under the line `RewriteEngine On` in `public/.htaccess`

So I changed my `public/.htaccess` to this and restarted apache2:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /selenium/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

However, the routes are still not working.
What else can I try?

### **System Infos**

**Apache version:**

> ```
> Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
> Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:32:47
> ```

**PHP version:**

```
PHP 7.0.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2017 13:50:00) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

**Linux version:**

> Linux linux 3.13.0-110-generic #157-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:55:25 UTC
>   2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Is this "not found" message from Apache or is it from Laravel? If it is Apache's message, look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/42610062/1741542

Comment: I would suggest to look if mod rewrite is enabled and if your apache settings permit use htaccess in that folder.(check AllowOverride directive)

Answer (score 2):

Many a times if its a fresh install of Ubuntu and you install apache, the `rewrite` module is not enabled by default. 
Run the following in your terminal

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now since the rewrite module is enabled, the `.htaccess` from your laravel project's public folder will be read and routes will work as intended.

I did not have to change any line in the default .htaccess file in laravel.
Hope this helps.